# Получение объекта из TreeSet

Tags: java, дерево

Есть `TreeSet`состоящий из объектов класса `User` как получить первый элемент коллекции? В классе `User` нет геттеров и сеттеров.
Код `User`:

```
class User {
String name;
int age;

User(String n, int a) {
    name = n;
    age = a;
}
```

}

Код `Main`:

```
    class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         TreeSet<User> tree = new TreeSet<>(new Comparator<User>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(User o1, User o2) {
                return o1.age - o2.age;
            }
        });
        tree.add(new User("Ivanov Ivan",30));
tree.add(new User("Stasov Stanislav",16));
    }
}
```

`User` и `Main` находятся в одном пакете

Answer (score 2):

С помощью метода `first`, вот так:

```
User firstUser = tree.first();
```

Официальная документация [TreeSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html)